# Dart how to determine the source of an on click event

Tags: event-handling, dart

I have some radio buttons; some action takes place when a button is clicked.  How can I implement code that simulates a click event and detect if the 'click' was caused by the simulation or the user?

```
chkBxB12 = querySelector('#B12');
chkBxB12.onClick.listen(chkBxB12Clicked);

void chkBxB12Clicked(Event e) {
  // do something
  // if mouse click or tap then
  //   do some-additional-thing 
}

foo() {
    chkBxB12.click()
{
```

[edit]

I modified JAre's example to better suit my needs (and reduce 8 methods to handle my four radio buttons to two - Robert's example reminded me of that need).  Here's the modified code that allows determination if a target button is clicked (or tapped) by hardware of software and the identity of the button.

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').onClick.listen(foo);
  foo(new MouseEvent("synthetic")); // parameter is
}



void foo(MouseEvent event) {
  if (event.target is Element){
    Element target = event.target;
    if(target.id == 'radio1')
      print('${event.type} target ${target.id}');
    else if(target.id == 'radio2')
      print('${event.type} target ${target.id}');
  }
  else {
    if(event.type == "synthetic") print(event.type);
    else print("It didn't work!");
  }
}
```

Output is as expected:

```
synthetic
click target radio1
click target radio2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `EventTarget` with `e.target` [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) and check it's type

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelector("#sample_text_id")
      ..text = "Click me!"
      ..onClick.listen(foo);
  foo(new MouseEvent("synthetic"));
}

void foo(MouseEvent event) {
  if (event.target is Element){
    Element target = event.target;
    target.text = "Hello dart";
  }
  else print(event.type);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is my little example:

.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').onClick.listen((MouseEvent e) {
    print('detail=${e.detail}');
    print('offset=${e.offset}');
    print('client=${e.client}');
    print('layer=${e.layer}');
    print('screen=${e.screen}');
  });

  RadioButtonInputElement radio1 = querySelector('#radio1');
  radio1.click();
}
```

.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test click</title>
    <script async type="application/dart" src="test_click.dart"></script>
    <script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">
  </body>
</html>
```

You asked for how to detect if the user has clicked or it was "simulated":

The output of this test is:

```dart
detail=0
offset=Point(-13, -11)
client=Point(0, 0)
layer=Point(0, 0)
screen=Point(0, 0)

detail=1
offset=Point(3, 1)
client=Point(16, 12)
layer=Point(16, 12)
screen=Point(1936, 73)
```

The first output is from a "simulated" click. The second one from a real click. I'd check for detail (I wasn't able to tell what this value means) or offset property on the event.

This should answer your question.

**EDIT**

After doing some research you should use the detail property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.detail#Notes

> For mouse events [...] the detail property indicates how many times the mouse has been clicked [...]

So this should be the best solution.

Regards
Robert

Comment: In ie detail=0 but offset,client and layer are each less than 0. So you could fallback to these Points then.

Comment: I think it will be cleaner solution to to make your own event objects instead of using `.click()` Normally you need extra abstraction layer over UI events anyway, especially if you want to support touch - because it highly inconsistent between browsers and platforms.